# How to view the contents of this array in TradingView?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a pinescript array declared like this;

```
var array_contents = array.new_float(2)
```

Assume that the contents of this array have been assigned.

How can I view the contents of each element in the array in pinescript? I am open to any method (`printchar(), plot(), table.new()` etc)

I am using pine-script v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pinescript library comes in handy. It is simple to use and solves the problem.

https://in.tradingview.com/script/Bcm0mGop-pta-plot/

```
import protradingart/pta_plot/7 as pp
pp.print_array_float(array_contents)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to print dynamic values you should use a `table`. Get the array size with `array.size()` and figure out how many columns you need. Then create your table with `table.new()`.

After that loop over the contents of your array and use `table.cell()` to fill your cells.